# Why mediation test suite does not find adcolony ad sources for banner ad?

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, adcolony

My Ad serving has been limited in Admob stating the issue account being assessed for around 2 months. It is stated [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9493252?hl=en) that

> Limited ad serving applies to AdMob Network only and doesn’t affect third-party mediation, house ads, and direct sold campaigns.

Therefore, I want to use AdMob mediation and started with integrating adcolony. I have followed step by step recommended approach from [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/adcolony) and [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation-test-suite). However, I do not find adcolony ad sources below the title Waterfall ad sources in the mediation test suit.

Here are the dependencies I am using:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.3.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:1.5.0'
```

I am testing for a banner ad unit and no ads are loaded in the app. If I load an ad using a mediation test suit from the AdMob network, test ad loads. I think this is expected as my ad serving is limited. But I do not know why adcolony is not listed in the test suite. Also, the AdColony test ad is not loading in my app. I wonder if there is any other way to test the mediation.

Answer (score 0):

For testing mediation ads using **mediation-test-suite** no need to use **com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.3.0.0**

you need to check in you application before load banner ads to if AdColony mediation adapter is available or not like.

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            Map<String, AdapterStatus> statusMap = initializationStatus.getAdapterStatusMap();
            for (String adapterClass : statusMap.keySet()) {
                AdapterStatus status = statusMap.get(adapterClass);
                Log.d("MyApp", String.format(
                        "Adapter name: %s, Description: %s, Latency: %d",
                        adapterClass, status.getDescription(), status.getLatency()));
            }

            // Start loading ads here...
        }
    });
```